# This python string sorting works but it shouldn't. Should it?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Taking an intro to python course, the following code sorts the string words appropriately, but the function does not return `sortString`, so I'm not understanding why the output is correct. Can you please help me understand?

```
def sort_words(string):
     splitString = string.split()
     sortString = splitString.sort()
     return splitString
print(sort_words('python is pretty cool'))
```

Comment: I don't see why not.. `str.split()` returns a `list`, which is then sorted in-place by `list.sort()`.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. `list.sort()` doesn't return anything (returns `None`), which you assign to `sortString`.

Answer (score 1):

Python `.sort()` returns `None`, much like `print()` does. `list.sort()` works in place - meaning the `list` is sorted without needing to assign it to another variable name.